# Java Hibernate Logging: Before or after sql eexectuion

Tags: hibernate

We have in the logging something like

```
09:53:02 server-1 java[5447]: 2022-03-10 09:53:02.262  INFO 5447 --- [io-18081-exec-6] a.w.w.service.item.LibItemService        : logging start
09:53:07 server-1 java[5447]: 2022-03-10 09:53:07.477 DEBUG 5447 --- [io-18081-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('lib_id_seq')
```

Logging is done via

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: TRACE
```

We are now discussing if the information about the SQL statement is **before** it is executed or **after**. The difference is: Whom to blame for the lost 5.2 seconds? The database OR the code which is done before?

Answer (score 0):

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) mentions that the code is generated by

> The Spring/Hibernate classes, which generate SQL statements and set
> the parameters

So I would say "Before".

Edit: However, by browsing the logs with a long query, I got this:

```
2022-08-02 11:45:24.970  WARN 53550 --- [nio-2061-exec-2] c.i.c.s.cases.list.CaseQueryService      : My log just before the query
2022-08-02 11:45:26.868 DEBUG 53550 --- [nio-2061-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        :
```

Notice the ~2s duration before logging the SQL. So, actually, I'd say "after"!